# How to save an image with the Python Image Library

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am a beginner in Python, so this question might be stupid but unfortunatly I can't figure it out on my own.

With the following script I want to create a black image and save it under the following path: C://Users/User/Desktop/black.png

```
def create_file(x=1000,y=10):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (x,y), "black") #creates a new black image
    img.save('C://Users/User/Desktop/black.png')`
```

The point is now that I want to pretend the path, the filename and the filetyp with the function like that:

```
create_image(x=1000,y=10,path=C://Users/bsimon/Desktop/,filename=black,filetype=png)`
```

And there the struggle begins:

1. I cant find the exact Syntax how I can deliver the path (filename, filetyp) to the img.save function
2. I got errors by using a different filetyp than png. The line `img.save('C://Users/User/Desktop/black.png')` works fine but when I try to use `img.save('C://Users/User/Desktop/black.bmp')` instead for example, the program I run the script with (Blender) crashes or get stucked in an endless loop).

Comment: Well, the first problem is that you forgot the quotes around the default values for `path`, `filename`, and `filetype`, so your `def` statement presumably gives you a `NameError` or the like. But it would be nice if you showed us the code you tried and explained what was wrong with us, instead of trying to describe it and just tell us it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, don't try to ask two questions that are unrelated (except for happening to occur in the same program) in a single question. I'm not sure how you're even getting to the second problem if you can't get the syntax right, but presumably that means you can write a good example program to demonstrate the second problem, which means you can write a great separate question for it.

Comment: Assuming `path='C://Users/bsimon/Desktop'`, `filename='black'`, and `filetype='png'` then `img.save(os.path.join(path, filename+os.extsep+filetyp)` should work for supported `filetyp`s.

Comment: @abarnert thansk for your help. I got to the second problem because at before i just used the "rigorous" line  `img.save('C://Users/User/Desktop/rainbow.png')` and it worked. So I changed the ending of the file to `.bmp` to get an different filetype. But I see your point of writing a seperate question & I will do that. @martineau thanks, it works :)

Comment: One quick note on your second question: This _could_ be an issue of how PIL/Pillow was configured (especially if you're actually using the old PIL instead of the modern Pillow), so maybe sure to explain exactly how you installed it (e.g., "I downloaded Pillow‑2.8.1‑cp33‑none‑win32.whl off [Christoph Gohlke's Windows packages page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) and installed that" or "I ran `pip install pillow` and it looks like I've got version 2.8.0" or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're looking for is this:

```
def create_image(x=1000, y=10, path="C:/Users/bsimon/Desktop/",
                 filename="black", filetype="png"):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (x,y), "black")
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename + '.' + filetype)
    img.save(fullpath)
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
create_image(filename="empty")
```

Pass whatever arguments (with keyword) you want, and it'll use the default values for all the others (just as you were already using the default values for `x` and `y`).

---

Notice that you always need quotes around string literals in Python. You can't just write `filename=black`; that says the default value for `filename` is whatever value happens to be in the global variable `black` (and you probably don't have one, so you get a `NameError`), not the string `"black"`.

Next, to combine a base filename like `"black"` and an extension like `"png"` into a complete filename, Python doesn't have a function to do that, so you have to do it manually, like `filename + '.' + filetype`. But to combine a directory name like `C:/Users/bsimon/Desktop/` and a filename like `"black.png"`, Python *does* have a function, [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)—and you should use it, because there are some tricky edge cases you might get wrong otherwise.

Your problem #2 seems to be completely unrelated to your problem #1, so I won't answer it here; create a separate question for that.

Comment: Hey, thak you very much! Everythink works fine now. My misunderstanding was on the one hand side the quotes and on the other hand syntax with the fullpath in combination wit the os.path.join :) And sorry for putting 2 questions together.

Comment: @RothWar: No problem. It really is worth reading the help here—it's much better than at most sites, and they're constantly improving it—but most people learn by trial and error, and as long as you're willing to learn (rather than get defensive about your errors) nobody will really begrudge you…